# Using keywords with RSS feed links

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I learned from some sites (such as from [this](https://lorelle.wordpress.com/2006/03/27/customizing-rss-feed-links-for-wordpresscom-and-wordpress-sidebar-widgets/)) that I can use keywords with RSS feed links, but I have not succes when I try this with [a particular site](http://www.civic.md/angajari.feed?type=rss). Is this way of access RSS feeds a general one, or it is limited somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS is a data format, just like HTML.

If you want to get different data, then the server has to generate different data.

That needs server side code to be designed to generate different RSS (or different static files to be created).